# How to convert fixed point data to byte array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, hex

I have the following piece of code related to conversion of fixed point to byte array in matlab:

```
R2 = fi(R1,1,16,15); % R1 is a 2x2 matrix which contains floating point data in the range [-1,1]

[m,n] = size(R2);

% I tried this code.
% R3 = repmat('  ',m,n*2);
% temp = R2(1,1);
% R3(1,1) = temp.hex
```

but failed.

How can I convert the R2 data into a byte array R3.
Each element in R3 matrix must be the hexadecimal representation of corresponding elements in R2.

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to view the data in hex format in the command line output, you can type `format hex;`. You can go back to the ordinary representation using `format short;`.

---

The [`num2hex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2hex.html) function will output the hexadecimal representation of a number as a string. You will want to store the results in a cell array.

```
[m,n] = size(R2);
hexmat = num2hex(R2(:));
hexcell = mat2cell(hexmat,ones(m,1),16);
R3 = reshape(hexcell,[m n]);
```